# Help with Grub (Stopped working after windows 10 update)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

first of all I know there are a couple (maybe maaaany) threads about this issue but I still can't figure out what is wrong, grub was displaying and everything was working perfectly before a major windows 10 update. I'll link the bootInfo repair-tool gave me. Thanks in advance and hope anyone here has the time to help me...

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25776234/

And bcdedit looks like this:

http://i65.tinypic.com/2zzhnp1.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for using boot repair. The bottom few lines state "The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would restore the [(generic mbr)] MBR in sda, and make it boot on sda1.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s   fix-windows-boot" but last line reads "The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot" so go ahead and run boot-repair and allow it to "act on boot" or more likely than not actually install / fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The WIn10 Creators update deletes linux partitions.

Sectors 764,002,303 -  968,802,303 are unallocated. this is probably your linux partition.

`Testdisk` can be use to recover it. In most cases just recovery of the partition is enough to allow boot.
However, if you have attempted other boot repairs, those repairs may need to be reversed.